# strtr or str_replace inside foreach without killing the server

Tags: php

I've got these array of objects,

```
array (
    [0] => DataCON Object (
            [id] => 2
            [first_name] => Urek
            [last_name] => Mazino
            [email] => hello@world.com
            [phone] => 000-444-5555
            [date] => 2016-02-11 14:46:38
            .
            .
            .
            .
        )
    [1] => DataCON Object (
            [ID] => 3
            .
            .
            .
            .
        )
    )
```

I have created a function that loops through each object and return the  value based on the template provided by another function, but the problem is when I have more than 1 object result, it just kills the server, my goal is to have `<span class="{fname}">{ID} - {email}</span>` return to `<span class="Urek">2 - hello@world.com</span>`

Here's my code,

```
class Kill_Bill {
    .
    .
    .
    public function _get_data( $template ) {
        $object = $this->the_data_object();
        if ( !$object ) return ' to me';
        $to_her = '';
        foreach ( $object as $obj ) {

            $tags = array(
                '{id}'      => $obj->id,    
                '{fname}'   => $obj->first_name,    
                '{lname}'   => $obj->last_name,
                '{email}'   => $obj->email,
                .                       
                .   // This whole thing is killing my server with bytes exhuasted,              
                .   // it only works fine if there's a single object in an array,                   
            );                          
            $to_her .=  strtr( $template, $tags ); 

            #$to_her .= str_replace('{id}', $obj->id, $template ) // This works fine.
        }
        return $to_her;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

is there any better and faster method instead of str_replace that I can use to replace the template value with object values?

Comment: Roughly how big is $template? Also, do you know if preg_replace() performs any better?

Comment: What does `$template` look like? Is this the whole template? `<span class="{fname}">{ID} - {email}</span>`

Comment: the ```$template``` is save on the database, could be around 500 - 2000  characters or even more, its a combination of html tags, text, word, number, like an article

Comment: And you want one `template` placed into `$to_her` for each occurance of the array? Right? Then the next question is how many occurances are there in the array

Comment: yes, only one, say, I  a table and wanted to display the objects values by replacing the tag ```{id}```, ```{fname}``` etc with the value of the object,

Comment: Please don't comment out the code you're asking about. The SO code highlighting makes it hard to read that part.

Comment: From the `strtr` documentation: **However, this function will be the most efficient when all the keys have the same size.** I guess you're seeing the efficiency problem because you have lots of different-sized keys.

Comment: I doesn't seem like you should be running out of memory. This process doesn't seem that intensive to me. What's your memory limit (see phpinfo())? Note, using preg_replace() will most likely use more memory. str_replace should be the most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can replace all 3 ( or more if required ) placeholders in the same `str_replace()` statement. The `search` and `replace` parameters can be arrays of things to look for and things to replace them with.

```
 $to_her .= str_replace( array('{id}', '{fname}', '{email}'), 
                         array($obj->id, $obj->first_name, $obj->email), 
                         $template );
```